# Using apply with splice function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to understand how splice and apply is working in below js code snippet.  start and rows are the integer values and loadedBatches, virtualCars are arrays. Can anyone explain what would virtualCars contain after executing these two lines?

```
Array.prototype.splice.apply(virtualCars, [...[start, rows], ...loadedBatches]);
virtualCars = [...virtualCars];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array should be an array with single values (being all the parameters `splice` expects):

```js
let virtualCars = ["Renault", "Mercedes", "Fiat", "Ferrari"];
console.log(`Initial ${JSON.stringify(virtualCars)}`);
let start = 0;
let rows = 2;

const loadedBatches = ["Volkswagen", "Zastava"];
[].splice.apply(virtualCars, [start, rows].concat(loadedBatches));
//                            ^ this should be a single array
console.log(`After first splice ${JSON.stringify(virtualCars)}`);

// or flatten the array, something like:
const otherBatch = ["Seat", "Nissan"];
start = 3;
[].splice.apply(virtualCars, [...[start, rows], ...otherBatch].flat());
console.log(`After second splice ${JSON.stringify(virtualCars)}`);

// or just splice directly, spreading the values to insert
const usBatch = ["Ford", "Tesla"];
start = 2;
rows = 3;
virtualCars.splice(start, rows, ...usBatch);
console.log(`After third splice ${JSON.stringify(virtualCars)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

The second positional argument in `apply()` will simply be an array of arguments that will be supplied to the `Array.prototype.splice()` argument. That array looks confusing at first: `[...[start, rows], ...loadedBatches]`, but it is essentially `[start, rows, ...loadedBatches]`.

[Looking at the specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#parameters), you will be:

1. Starting the array manipulating at the index provided at `start`
2. `rows` will be the `deleteCount` parameter, which determines how many items to delete from the array starting at the `start` index
3. `...loadedBatches` simply spreads all the elements in the `loadedBatches` array, which will be the appended to the array at the `start` index.

In other words, the code will:

1. Convert `virtualCars` into an array
2. Delete number of rows, determined by the value of `rows`, starting at the index specified by `start`
3. Add all items in `loadedBatches` from the index specified by `start`